# Python 3.2 Beautiful Soup alternative

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I need to make a web crawler to extract information from web pages. I made a research and found that [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) was excellent since i could parse all document and create dom objects and iterate, extract attributes, etc(similitar to JQuery).

But I'm using Python 3.2 and there is no stable version for it(I think there isn't at all, just 3.1 I saw at their home page).

So I need some as good alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) homepage:

> The latest release works with all CPython versions from 2.4 to 3.2.

Comment: I just read Beautiful Soup 3.1 series works with Python 3.0 and that's it(There is no mention to 3.2). And that 3.x versions uses an HTMLParser since the SGMLParser(which is much better) got removed :/. And there is no more support from the author.

Comment: @Jirico: That's why I recommend using lxml.

Comment: lxml doesn't look so hot as Beautiful Soup, but I will give it a look. Thanks! Hmm I Think I will get Python 2.7 I will have more support from third parties...

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like there is a version of beautiful soup of 3.2.0 released almost a year ago. There's also HTMLParser http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: I just tried Beautiful Soup 3.2.0. the setup is giving me syntax error at the statement: print "Unit tests have failed!". It's the old print statement from 2.x how can u tell me it's ok for 3.2?

Comment: Report the bug (with traceback) to the [BS support group](http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup), just like they ask. They're pretty helpful, give them a chance to fix it before you start posting here that it doesn't work. (Unless [this](http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup/browse_thread/thread/6c13e079839306ca/a3c2209e3d90f45d?lnk=gst&q=3.2+unittest#a3c2209e3d90f45d) was already you reporting it)

Answer (score 2):

I think the latest release is 4.1.1, you can read about it here [BS4 Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

I have used BS4 with PHP on my website for this purpose for a while now, with great results.  I had to switch back to BSv3 because of a PHP / Python incompatibility issue, but that is separate from how well the BS4 script works by itself.

Initially I uses the built in HTML Parsing engine, but found this slow.  After installing the LMXL engine on my web server, massive increase in speed!  No noticable improvement in the actual parsing, but the speed increased dramatically.

Id give it a go - I reccomend it, and I tried a LOT of different options before I settled on Beautiful soup.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The most direct and best alternative to BeautifulSoup is [Mechanize](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Mechanize is your saviour if you need to automate simple web page functionality, such as submitting a form (with information you didn't have beforehand, like CSRF tokens). It's even available in multiple programming languages!

That said, Sven's answer is right: I love lxml when I just need to *extract* information from HTML.

Comment: I'm posting this answer because just today I wondered "oh, what was that library which was so much superior to BS that I got furious anyone still used BS?" and I had forgotten that Mechanize is also for Python. So I think it bears repeating!